# using sed to find a match in a file and replace it with the content of other file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a content file something like this:

content.json (array of objects)

```
[
{ "interval": 1, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 2, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
]
```

There is a config file which has similar content but diffrent value.

config.json (object value)

```
{ "interval": 3, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 4, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
```

My target is to append the content of config.json file to content.json file, so that the new content.json file will become:

```
[
{ "interval": 1, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 2, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 3, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 4, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
]
```

My idea is to find `},\n]` regex from content.json file and replace it with the content of config.json file. Since I am running these command remotely, my idea is to run it as single command using sed. But somehow I am not getting any proper documentation/ help in sed to achieve this.

Can anyone please help here.

Comment: You should look into [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for processing JSON

Comment: There are also more standard ways to work with json . You can use [python API](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your two json files are wrong.

In the first you must remove the final comma

```
[
{ "interval": 1, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 2, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]}
]
```

In the last you must add square brackets and remove the last comma

```
[
{ "interval": 3, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 4, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]}
]
```

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) on these two files and running

```
jq -sc add input01.json input02.json
```

you will have

```
[
{"interval":1,"expired":3,"ignored":[".git",".p4"]},
{"interval":2,"expired":4,"ignored":[".git",".p4"]},
{"interval":3,"expired":3,"ignored":[".git",".p4"]},
{"interval":4,"expired":4,"ignored":[".git",".p4"]}
]
```